# Update iframe clicking button jquery and array

Tags: jquery

I have setup an iframe on my page and would like it to update when clicking on a next button.

I have an array of urls which I want to be called when the next button is clicked.

The next button should load the next url in the iframe.

I am stuck at how do i always call the next index position each time i click the next button?

Comment: If my answer below has helped you, please be sure to click the checkmark to the left of it so it's green, marking it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var pos = 0;
var urlArray = [...]; //Put your array of URLs here
$('#next').click(function() {
    if (pos == urlArray.length)
        pos = -1; //Reset it back to the beginning so it'll loop and not throw an exception.
    $('#youriframe').attr('src', urlArray[++pos]); //note the pre increment (++)
});
```

Comment: This solution worked well for me. I'm now adding to the if statement so that the position decrements when clicking on previous.